# What does IntelliJ's build project automatically do?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, jar, dropwizard

I am working on a [DropWizard](https://www.dropwizard.io/en/stable/) project for the first time which uses the `docker-config.yml` file to run the server using the jar file.

The command I run on the terminal to run the server is something like this:

```
java -jar target/foo-0.0.1.jar server conf/docker-conf.yml
```

I have to run `mvn package` every single time I make a change (even for a small change like `System.out.println();`).

Will toggling the `build project automatically` in Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler accomplish this task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Run mvn package every time I make changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58717271/run-mvn-package-every-time-i-make-changes)

Comment: @zloster Nope..

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51437504/is-there-a-way-to-automatically-compile-using-maven-after-code-changes-when-usin/51437852